# opencart include 3rd subcategory in menu

Tags: menu, addition, categories, opencart

I added 4 categories as 4 level in opencart admin panel,

```
Home
Home -> Furniture
Home -> Furniture -> Wooden (Getting menus up to this level)
Home -> Furniture -> wooden -> Lightweight (Need to display this level)
```

Initially i had a problem in displaying 3rd level category in menu.
I enabled that third level menu using this [post](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=42503#p369429)

Like this how to enable 4th level categories too.

Comment: Stack overflow is going quiet slow..

Answer (score 2):

**header controller**

```
$data['categories'] = array();

    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {

                // Level 3 sultan
                $children_data_3 = array();

                $children_3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

                foreach ($children_3 as $child_3) {

                    $filter_data_3 = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child_3['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $children_data_3[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child_3['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data_3) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_3['category_id'])
                    );
                }
                //end of level 3


                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                    'grand_childs' => $children_data_3

                );
            }

            // Level 1
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }

    }
```

**tpl code**

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>


    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>

      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
          <ul class="nav">
            <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>

              <li class="dropdown-submenu" >
              <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>

               <?php if($child['grand_childs']){
                echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">';
              foreach($child['grand_childs'] as $grand_child){ ?>
                        <li>
                          <a href="<?php echo $grand_child['href']; ?>" ><?php echo $grand_child['name']; ?></a>
                        </li>
            <?php }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            ?>
            </li>


            <?php } ?>

          </ul>
          <?php } ?>

        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> </div>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First download vqmod from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/vqmod/downloads) then extract it.Now vqmod folder keep in your site root directory. Then go to browser write your site url then "/vqmod/install" and press enter then you get a message that you can install vqmod in your site successfully. Now you download a extension form [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=21351) and extract it. and keep extract file in your site indicate foulder exm: menu3rdlevel-opencart-2_2\vqmod\xml/Menu3rdLevel.xml file in your site  eg : vqmod\xml/Menu3rdLevel.xml them other file with "menu3rdlevel" folder. From your extension folder "javascript" to your site folder "javescript", extension folder "image" to site folder "image" extension folder "stylsheet" to site folder "stylsheet". then refresh your site in browser its ok now.

NB: Transfer xml file only file and other file with "menu3rdlevel" folder.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the subcategories in the main menu . Please do the following changes.

Edit header.php controller file

```
 $sec_children_data = array();
                $sec_children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

                foreach ($sec_children as $sec_child) {
                    $sec_children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $sec_child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? '' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $sec_child['category_id'])
                    );

                }
```

Edit header.tpl

```
?php if (isset($category['children'][$i]['level3'])) {  
          $level3menus = $category['children'][$i]['level3'];
          ?>
          <ul class="level3">
          <?php
                foreach( $level3menus as $level3menu) {
          ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $level3menu['href']; ?>" class=""><?php echo $level3menu['name'];?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
```

Please refer my tutorial for step by step explanation and demo.

Answer (score -1):

I done it myself,

Change your header.tpl file to

```
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && !strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6')) echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'. "\n"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<base href="<?php echo $base; ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<?php if ($description) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($keywords) { ?>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($icon) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $icon; ?>" rel="icon" />
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach ($links as $link) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $link['href']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $link['rel']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/fashioncart/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
<link rel="<?php echo $style['rel']; ?>" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $style['href']; ?>" media="<?php echo $style['media']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/external/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/colorbox.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/fashioncart/javascript/fashioncart_custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/fashioncart/javascript/cloud_zoom.js"></script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<?php foreach ($scripts as $script) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $script; ?>"></script>
<?php } ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/fashioncart/stylesheet/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/fashioncart/stylesheet/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/ie6.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
DD_belatedPNG.fix('#logo img');
</script>
<![endif]-->
<?php echo $google_analytics; ?>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="header">
  <?php if ($logo) { ?>
  <div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
  <?php } ?>

      <div id="welcome">
        <?php if (!$logged) { ?>
        <?php echo $text_welcome; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php echo $text_logged; ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>

     <div class="sign_up_pd">
        <a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a> <a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $publisher_sign; ?> " title="Publisher" > Publisher </a>
        <a href="<?php echo $developer_sign; ?> " title="Developer" > Developer </a>
     </div>
     <div class="clear_both"></div>

      <?php echo $cart; ?>


  <div id='header_btm'>
  <span class="span_lable">Search: </span>
    <select name="search_categories" id="search_categories" >
    <option value="0" >All Category</option>
      <?php foreach ($categories_search as $category) { ?>
            <?php if($category['category_id'] == $filter_category_id): ?>
            <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>" ><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
            <?php else: ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>" ><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $subcategory) { ?>
            <?php if($subcategory['category_id'] == $filter_category_id): ?>
            <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $subcategory['category_id'];?>" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $subcategory['name'];?></option>
            <?php else: ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $subcategory['category_id'];?>" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $subcategory['name'];?></option>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php } ?>


     <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <div id="search">
        <div class="search_inside">
            <?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
            <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" />
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#444444';" />
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="button-search"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php echo $language; ?>
    <?php echo $currency; ?>
  </div>

</div>

<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><span class='home_icon'></span></a>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>               
            <!-- Begin Part 1 of the extension Header menu add level 3 sub categories extension (line to be replaced: number 84 of the header.tpl file) -->      
            <li>
            <?php
            if(count($category['children'][$i]['children_level2'])>0){
            ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"  onmouseover='JavaScript:openSubMenu("<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['id']; ?>")'><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a>
            <?php

                  //echo "<img src='catalog/view/theme/default/image/arrow-right.png' style='right:10px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute;'/></a>";
                  //echo "<span style='right:5px;margin-top:-6px;position:absolute;color:white;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;'>&#187;</span></a>";

            }
            else
            {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>" onmouseover='JavaScript:closeSubMenu()' ><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <?php if ($category['children'][$i]['children_level2']) { ?>
                 <div class="submenu" style="display:none;" id="id_menu_<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['id']; ?>">
                  <ul>
                  <?php for ($wi = 0; $wi < count($category['children'][$i]['children_level2']); $wi++) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <!-- Begin 4th level -->
<?php
            if(count($category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['children_level3'])>0){
            ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['href']; ?>"  ><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['name']; ?></a>
            <?php

                  //echo "<img src='catalog/view/theme/default/image/arrow-right.png' style='right:10px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute;'/></a>";
                  //echo "<span style='right:5px;margin-top:-6px;position:absolute;color:white;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;'>&#187;</span></a>";

            }
            else
            {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['href']; ?>"  ><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['name']; ?></a>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <?php if ($category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['children_level3']) { ?>
                 <div class="submenu"  syule="display:none;" id="id_menu_<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['id']; ?>">
                  <ul>
                  <?php for ($wid = 0; $wid < count($category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['children_level3']); $wid++) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wid]['children_level3']['href']; ?>"  ><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['children_level2'][$wi]['children_level3'][$wid]['name']; ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
              <?php } ?>
            </ul>
           </div>
<?php } ?>   

<!-- End 4th Level -->
                    </li>
              <?php } ?>
            </ul>
           </div>
           <?php } ?>        
         </li>
         <!-- END Part 1 of the extension Header menu add level 3 sub categories extension -->
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="notification"></div>
<!-- Begin Part 2 of the extension Header menu add level 3 sub categories extension-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function openSubMenu(id){
        //
        $('.submenu').hide();
        document.getElementById("id_menu_"+id).style.display="block";
}
function closeSubMenu(){
      $('.submenu').hide();
}
</script>
<style>
.submenu{
    background: url('catalog/view/theme/default/image/menu.png') repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    margin-top:-23px;
    left:140px;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 .submenu {left: 160px;}

    }
</style>


<!-- PHONE::Start -->

<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu-phone" class="shown-phone" style="display: none;">
  <div id="menu-phone-button">Menu</div>
  <select id="menu-phone-select" onchange="location = this.value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Bind the Phone menu dropdown
    $('#menu-phone-button').bind('click', function() {
        $("#menu-phone-select").css({'opacity':'1'});
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>

<!-- PHONE::End -->

<div id="notification"></div>
```

And change your header.php file to

```
<?php   
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
   protected function index() {
      $this->data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();

      if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
         $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
      } else {
         $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_url');
      }

      $this->data['description'] = $this->document->getDescription();
      $this->data['keywords'] = $this->document->getKeywords();
      $this->data['links'] = $this->document->getLinks();    
      $this->data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
      $this->data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();
      $this->data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
      $this->data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');
      $this->data['google_analytics'] = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_google_analytics'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

      // Whos Online
      if ($this->config->get('config_customer_online')) {
         $this->load->model('tool/online');

         if (isset($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            $ip = $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'];   
         } else {
            $ip = ''; 
         }

         if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_HOST']) && isset($this->request->server['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            $url = 'http://' . $this->request->server['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->request->server['REQUEST_URI'];   
         } else {
            $url = '';
         }

         if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
            $referer = $this->request->server['HTTP_REFERER'];   
         } else {
            $referer = '';
         }

         $this->model_tool_online->whosonline($ip, $this->customer->getId(), $url, $referer);
      }

      $this->language->load('common/header');

      if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
         $server = HTTPS_IMAGE;
      } else {
         $server = HTTP_IMAGE;
      }   

      if ($this->config->get('config_icon') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_icon'))) {
         $this->data['icon'] = $server . $this->config->get('config_icon');
      } else {
         $this->data['icon'] = '';
      }

      $this->data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

      if ($this->config->get('config_logo') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'))) {
         $this->data['logo'] = $server . $this->config->get('config_logo');
      } else {
         $this->data['logo'] = '';
      }

      $this->data['text_home'] = $this->language->get('text_home');
      $this->data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
      $this->data['text_shopping_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_shopping_cart');
       $this->data['text_search'] = $this->language->get('text_search');
      $this->data['text_welcome'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_welcome'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL'));
      $this->data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
      $this->data['text_account'] = $this->language->get('text_account');
       $this->data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');

      $this->data['publisher_sign'] = $this->url->link('account/publisher_signup', '', 'SSL');

      $this->data['developer_sign'] = $this->url->link('account/developer_signup', '', 'SSL');

      $this->data['home'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
      $this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', 'SSL');
      $this->data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
      $this->data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL');
      $this->data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
      $this->data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');

      if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
         $this->data['filter_name'] = $this->request->get['filter_name'];
      } else {
         $this->data['filter_name'] = '';
      }

      // Menu
      $this->load->model('catalog/category');

      $this->load->model('catalog/product');

      $this->data['categories'] = array();

      $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

      foreach ($categories as $category) {
         if ($category['top']) {
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
               $data = array(
                  'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                  'filter_sub_category' => true
               );               
               /*Begin of the extension Header menu add level 3 sub categories extension code  to be replaced:
               $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data); 

               $children_data[] = array(
                  'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                  'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])   
               );   
               */             
               // Level 2
               $children_level2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);
               $children_data_level2 = array();
               foreach ($children_level2 as $child_level2) {
                     $data_level2 = array(
                           'filter_category_id'  => $child_level2['category_id'],
                           'filter_sub_category' => true
                     );

                     //level3 starts here

                     $children_level3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child_level2['category_id']);
                     $children_data_level3 = array();
                     foreach ($children_level3 as $child_level3) 
                        {
                           $data_level3 = array(
                                 'filter_category_id'  => $child_level3['category_id'],
                                 'filter_sub_category' => true
                           );
                           $product_total_level3 = '';
                           if ($this->config->get('config_product_count')) {
                                 $product_total_level3 = ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data_level3) . ')';
                           }

                           $children_data_level3[] = array(
                                 'name'  =>  $child_level3['name'] . $product_total_level3,
                                 'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_level3['category_id']),
                                 'id' => $category['category_id']. '_' . $child['category_id']. '_' . $child_level3['category_id']
                           );
                        }
                     //level 3 ends here
                     $product_total_level2 = '';
                     if ($this->config->get('config_product_count')) {
                           $product_total_level2 = ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data_level2) . ')';
                     }

                     $children_data_level2[] = array(
                           'name'  =>  $child_level2['name'] . $product_total_level2,
                           'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_level2['category_id']),
                           'id' => $category['category_id']. '_' . $child['category_id']. '_' . $child_level2['category_id'],
                           'children_level3' => $children_data_level3,
                     );
               }
               $children_data[] = array(
                     'name'  => $child['name'],
                     'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                     'id' => $category['category_id']. '_' . $child['category_id'],
                     'children_level2' => $children_data_level2,
               );
               //END of the extension Header menu add level 3 sub categories extension         
            }

            // Level 1
            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
               'name'     => $category['name'],
               'children' => $children_data,
               'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
               'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );

         }
      }

      if (isset($this->request->get['filter_category_id'])) {

         $filter_category_id = $this->request->get['filter_category_id'];

      } else {

         $filter_category_id = 0;

      }

      $this->data['filter_category_id'] = $filter_category_id;



      foreach ($categories as $category) {

            $children_data = array();



            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);



            foreach ($children as $child) {

               $data = array(

                     'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],

                     'filter_sub_category' => true

               );



               $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);



               $children_data[] = array(

                     'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),

                     'category_id' => $child['category_id']

               );

            }



            // Level 1

            $this->data['categories_search'][] = array(

                  'name'     => $category['name'],

                  'category_id' => $category['category_id'],

                  'children' => $children_data,

            );



      }


      $this->children = array(
         'module/language',
         'module/currency',
         'module/cart'
      );

      if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
         $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl';
      } else {
         $this->template = 'default/template/common/header.tpl';
      }

       $this->render();
   }    
}
?>
```